# modal dialog popup alarm

Tags: linux, ubuntu, notifications, alert

In Linux, specifically Ubuntu, is there a way to set a simple command to alert me at a specific time? **preferably w/ a pop-up so I won't miss it**.

Perhaps pair some command w/ "at" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to edit a file called *cron* that let you run things at specific times. For information about how to use it run `man cron`on a terminal and read the examples at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron_%28Unix%29).

Edit cron to run a bash at the times when you need.

The bash file should looks like this

```
zenity --info --text 'You alert message'
```

---

The message will look like this:

[image]

Comment: I guess this dialog is not modal, understanding modality as same as wikipedia does: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window

Answer (score 0):

I would favour libnotify  in combination with [indicator-notification applet](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/03/how-to-never-miss-an-ubuntu-notification-again/) so you won't miss any notifications. To install both:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jconti/recent-notifications
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libnotify-bin indicator-notifications
```

And finally login and logout. Now you should be able to use notify-send to send notifications. This works easy as long as you send yourself notifications. For sending notifications to other users this is a bit challenging, but especially for `root` to `you` there is no problem by using a proper `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`.

Please not this notifications arent *modal*.